# How to display an image using Swagger 2.0 ?

Tags: rest, flask, swagger, mongoengine, flask-restful

I'm coding a photo web application using mongoengine, flask, connexion and swagger 2.0 to define my API. The idea is to have an API about the photographers who post the photos and an other API about the photos.

I'm defining my yaml file for the photo API. We have two methods post( to upload a photo) and get using the id of the photo to retrieve it.

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: Photo service API
  version: "0.1"

paths:
  /photo:
    post:
      tags:
        - "Photo"
      operationId: photo_service.post_photo
      summary: Add a new photo
      consumes:
         - multipart/form-data
      parameters:
        - name: photo_name
          in: formData
          description: "file to upload"
          required: true
          type: string
        - name: photo_file
          in: formData
          description: "file to upload"
          required: true
          type: file 
      responses:
        201:
          description: New photo added
          schema:
            properties:
              photo_file:
                  type: object
                  description: Information about the photo 
        409:
          description: Photo already exists

  /photo/{photo_id}:
    get:
      tags: 
        - "Specific photo"
      operationId: photo_service.get_photo
      summary: Get specific photo.
      produces:
        - image/png
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/parameters/photo_id'
      responses:
        200:
          description: Return the requested photo.
          schema:
             type: file              
        404:
          description: Photo does not exist.
```

The Photo class is pretty simple for test purposes:

```
class Photo(Document):
    photo_name = StringField(max_length=120, required=True)
    photo_file = ImageField()
```

I've coded the following functions which corresponds to the functions called in Operation Id field of the Yaml file:

```
def get_photo(photo_id):
    try:
        ph = mongo_get_photo(photo_id)
    except (Photo.DoesNotExist, InvalidId) as e:
        return 'Not Found', 404
    except pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError as sste:
        return 'Mongo unavailable', 503
    return ph

def post_photo(photo_name,photo_file):                                           
    try:                                                                                                                                        
        ph = mongo_add (photo_name,photo_file)                          
        return 'Created', 201, {'location': '/photo/' + str(ph.id)} 
    except pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError as sste:                  
        return 'Mongo unavailable', 503
```

And since i'm using mongodb as a data base. I'm using a wrapper to make request to my db:

```
@robustify.retry_mongo
def mongo_add(photo_name,photo_file):
    ph = Photo(photo_name = photo_name)
    ph.photo_file.put(photo_file)
    ph.save()
    return ph

@robustify.retry_mongo
def mongo_get_photo(photo_id):
    ph = Photo.objects(id=ObjectId(photo_id)).first()
    photo = ph.photo_file.read()
    return photo
```

My problem is that the POST method seems to be working. I'm creating a 200 code response whenever i try to post a png picture. But the get method doesn't work. It seems to be a problem with the way mongodb handles the file. Is it a problem with the way i'm reading the image file in the function mongo_get_photo ? Does anyone have a clue please ?

Would it be better to store the image as a string by converting it in base 64 before ?

Thanks !